# Finding negative at which cross correlation is abs(maximum ccf( ))

Tags: r

I have two time series and I am using ccf to find the cross correlation between them. ccf(ts1, ts2) lists the cross-correlations for all time lags. And then I use the absolute maximum function to help me find out the absolute maximum correlation, [Finding lag at which cross correlation is maximum ccf( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369109/finding-lag-at-which-cross-correlation-is-maximum-ccf)

However, I found out that the return value is the absolute value of correlation, but I do want to get the origin value of correlation, which means that I want to know whether the correlation is negative or positive. what can I do?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Why not use the code from your link and, once you've found the index of the max value,  do `maxind<- which.max(absres$abscor,array.ind=TRUE); sign(absres$abscor[maxind])` or something similar to that.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I used the code from the link, but I found the return value is only the absolute value of the maximum correlation, the problem is I want to identify the whether this value is negative or positive. and I have tried what you coded, it seenms that something is wrong

Answer (score 1):

QUoting the function from the link:

```
Find_Abs_Max_CCF<- function(a,b)
{
 d <- ccf(a, b, plot = FALSE, lag.max = length(a)-5)
 cor = d$acf[,,1]
 abscor = abs(d$acf[,,1])
 lag = d$lag[,,1]
 res = data.frame(cor,lag)
 absres = data.frame(abscor,lag)
 absres_max = res[which.max(absres$abscor),]
 return(absres_max)
}
```

So, `maxind <- which.max(absres$abscor)` will return the index (location) of the maximum value of `abscor` .   Then `sign(d$acf[,,1][maxind])` will give you the algebraic sign of the original value prior to having taken the absolute value.   As it happens, this  is (or should be, if I backtracked correctly) reporting the sign of the value `absres_max`  .  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @user3169448  if this answer meets yr needs, please click the checkmark to accept.  Thanks!