# How to synchronize signals using a cross-correlation and FFT in R?

Tags: r, fft, cross-correlation

I have two signals that I want to synchronize (find the time lag).
I already did this using the "ccf" function and finding the maximum, following this post:

[Finding lag at which cross correlation is maximum ccf( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369109/finding-lag-at-which-cross-correlation-is-maximum-ccf)

I though I'd have to do something like

```
fft1 <- fft(my.vector1)
fft2 <- fft(my.vector2)
ccf(fft1, fft2, lag.max = 6000, plot = FALSE)
```

However, for efficiency reasons, I would like to implement the cross-correlation with the fast fourier transform (FFT), as suggested in other posts.
I have many tests with 300.000 samples (1.5 minutes sampled at 2000Hz), and a maximum lag of -3 to 3 seconds.

Any hints on how to do that in R?

I know the `fft` and `ccf` functions, but don't know how to integrate them.

Comment: Unless you add a specific programming question, the question is bound for junk yard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross-correlation of two complex function equals the convolution of one function and the complex conjugate of the other:

[Cross correlation and convolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-Correlation.html)

As the function `convolve`  in R already uses the Fast Fourier Transform, all you have to do is:

```
convolve(my.vector1, my.vector2)
```

The maximum lag can be found by:

```
which.max(convolve(my.vector1,my.vector2))
```